# javascript instance method not found: Object #<Object> has no method 'handleRequest'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

the following code works:

```
Experimenters = function(db)
{
    Object.apply(this, arguments);
    this.db = db;
};
util.inherits(Experimenters, Object);


Experimenters.prototype.getAll = function(req, res)
{    
    return this.db.Experimenter.getAllExperimentersWithExperiments()
    .then(function(exptrs) {
        res.json(200, exptrs);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        res.json(500, error);
    });
};
```

however the code for each of my request handlers is pretty much all the same, so I thought I'd reduce duplicate code by creating a generic request handler:

```
Experimenters.prototype.handleRequest = function(promise, res)
{
    return promise
    .then(function(success){
        res.json(200, success);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        if (error instanceof dbErrors.NotFoundError) {
            res.json(404, error);
        } else if ((error instanceof dbErrors.ValidationError) ||
                   (error instanceof dbErrors.UniqueConstraintError)) {
            res.json(422, error);
        } else {
            // unknown error
            console.error(error);
            res.json(500, error);
        }
    });
};
```

And modify my request handlers like this:

```
Experimenters.prototype.getAll = function(req, res)
{
    this.handleRequest(
        this.db.Experimenter.getAllExperimentersWithExperiments(),
        res);
};
```

But I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'handleRequest'
```

the code is called via my routes/index.js

```
// edited for brevity
var Experimenters = require("../controllers/experimenters");

module.exports.initialize = function(app)
{
    var exptrs = new Experimenters(app.db);

    app.get("/api/experimenters", exptrs.getAll);
};
```

which is called from my app.js:

```
 //edited for brevity
 var config = require(path.join(__dirname, "..", "config")),
     createDB = require(path.join(__dirname, "models")),
     routes = require(path.join(__dirname, "routes"));

 var db = createDB(config);
 app.set("db", db);
 // edited for brevity
 routes.initialize(app);
```

Comment: The value of `this` inside the `getAll()` function depends on how the `getAll()` function is called, not how it's defined, and the code that calls the function seems to be missing in the above code ?

Comment: Likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: In the line 3,on the first script,I think nothing Will be run after the return statement.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. yeat it had to do with bind()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this the following way:

First, I noticed that my handleRequest() made no use of 'this', so it could be a simple function

Secondly, I modified handleRequest() by adding a Promise.try() around the promise

```
handleRequest = function(promise, res)
{
    return Promise.try(function(){
        return promise;
    })
    .then(function(success){
        res.json(200, success);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        if (error instanceof dbErrors.NotFoundError) {
            res.json(404, error);
        } else if ((error instanceof dbErrors.ValidationError) ||
                   (error instanceof dbErrors.UniqueConstraintError)) {
            res.json(422, error);
        } else {
            // unknown error
            console.error(error);
            res.json(500, error);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Yup that is because you are passing the function `exptrs.getAll` as a parameter into the `.get` function which is called by `app` so and `this` in `exptrs.getAll` will be referring to `app`.

Answer (score 2):

Updates:

you are getting this error because you should be binding `exptrs` to the function like this:

```
app.get("/api/experimenters", exptrs.getAll.bind(exptrs));
```

This is because you are passing the function `exptrs.getAll` as a parameter into the `.get` function which is called by `app` and therefore `this` in `exptrs.getAll` will be referring to `app`.

So another solution is to pass an anonymous function to `get`:

```
app.get("/api/experimenters", function(){exptrs.getAll()});
```

---

Normally when you get errors like `Object #<Object> has no method 'handleRequest'`, 
it either means

1. `.prototype.handleRequest()` is not defined properly, *or*
2. the object that is calling `.handleRequest()` is not actually the
   correct object.

I believe in the return of `.handleRequest` it should be `promise().then(...).catch(...)`, instead of `promise.then(...).catch(...)`, because just having `promise` without `()` you are not calling the function.

Similar to

```
var b = function(){
 return 1   
};

function a(c){
    return c
}

var d = a(b);

console.log(d);

//it will not log 1, unless 
//function a(c){
//  return c()
//}
```

And in `.getAll` you should be returning `this.handleRequest(..)` too, rather than just calling it.

Comment: interesting, so with exptrs.getAll.bind(this)  'this' refers to exptrs?

Comment: @ckot Sorry I made a careless mistake. The `this` in `exptrs.getAll.bind(this)` is referring to the `this` of `module.exports.initialize` and so doing `exptrs.getAll.bind(this)` will make `this` in `exptrs.getAll` refer to the `module.exports`. What you need to do is to bind(exptrs) so that `exptrs` will be the `this` in `exptrs.getAll`.

Comment: it was working anyway, but I added exptrs.getAll.bind(exptrs) and it didn't break anything.  Probably wasn't necessary for this simple request handler, but doing this to all of my handlers, which might call other instance methods, should be ensured to work, right?

Comment: @ckot Yeah, unless you want `this` in the function to refer to something else (in this case `app`). To learn more about `bind` you can check out this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).